# Counting average of all polygons instead of every polygon in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, query, area, function

I'm facing a problem with counting avg of all polygons in pgsql query. Instead of that I receive avg(of an area) of every polygon separately. My syntax is looking like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function(geometry, integer)
RETURNS geometry AS $$

DECLARE

c_density integer := avg(area(geom, 10)); 

BEGIN
RETURN(
SELECT ST_CollectionExtract(ST_Collect(points),1) as points FROM
(SELECT ST_Collect(function2($1, c_density), ST_Centroid($1)) as points) as points
);
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I want **c_density** to be constant. For example I have dataset with areas of:
    10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100
And I want to c_density to be 55 for every polygon. Instead of that it is like 10, 20, 30...etc. for every next one.

Function area is simply making square root from ST_Area for polygons.

Comment: What does function2 do? ST_Collect doees not create a polygon, it simply aggregates geometries, so your question is a bit hard to understand. Could you write the query you are running as a query, rather than plpgsql, with missing function definitions? It will be easier for us to read/debug.

Comment: What is 'geom'? One would expect something like 'select avg(area(geom)) from mylayer', i.e. Applied on the entire table

Comment: Ok, I'll try to explain everything. I'm preparing my group of polygons to create a heatmap. In this purpose I'm creating with function2 regular grid of points where c_density is CONSTANT distance between each point in grid. Then I have to aggregate grid and centroids with ST_Collect. In the future I want to execute this function like this:
    SELECT function(geom, 20) FROM my_table WHERE id = 'some_string'.

Comment: The first function is looking like this:

    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function(geometry, integer)
RETURNS integer AS
'SELECT sqrt(ST_Area($1)/$2)::int'
LANGUAGE sql;

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you want to create a new function at all, what you want is using AVG as a window aggregate as follows:

```
SELECT gid, geom, AVG(ST_Area(geom)) OVER() AS c_density
   FROM some_table;
```

Note if you want to have the average for some group, say groups in a county, you would add a PARTITION BY clause As  follows:

```
 SELECT gid, geom, AVG(ST_Area(geom)) OVER(PARTITION BY county) AS c_density
   FROM some_table;
```

BTW this topic and many others are covered in our book  PostgreSQL: Up and Running.  3rd edition due out in a little over a month --  http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920052715.do  sadly they haven't updated the cover yet.